# .replace isn't working on incorrect base64

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm connecting to the Google insights API, and attempting to pull in the image. I can't get it displaying and after a bit of research it was announced that the Base64 image had the wrong encoding/symbols. In order to get the image to work I need to replace all "_" with a "/", and all "-" with a "+".

Below you can see the code snippet I'm using to attempt this:

```
.replace('_', '/').replace('-', '+');
```

I'm saving the result from the API as a variable for convenience, and the code for this, including the replace, is:

```
desktop['screenshot'] = screenshot.replace('_', '/').replace('-', '+');
```

However myself and a colleague can not find why it isn't replacing, and after 3 hours of googling, I've come here.

Please can you advise on what is wrong/where it is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`.replace` method replacing first occurence of match by default([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)). But you need to replace all of occurences, try this:

```
desktop['screenshot'] = screenshot.replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/\-/g, '+');
```

Comment: Hey Andrey, thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, this hasn't had any effect. The base64 is still showing _'s instead of /'s and -'s instead of +'s. I did try the global flag as well, however it had no effect :(

Comment: @AshScott Can you post example base64 string?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mr2RQbbc - there's also some JS at the bottom below the string

Comment: @AshScott, the base64 url just doesn't work even if I replace all mannually, I found the original topic about pagespeed API and copied URI from there, and it worked fine - http://jsbin.com/gekekemiho/1/edit?html,js,output . So you shoud check not the replacing code, but URI itself, I guess something wrong with it